# Regex against CSV, what am I doing wrong

Tags: regex

I am using a regex in less to find the rows where the 6th column is an empty "".

I used the following regex:

```
^(.*?,){5}"",
```

But it matches this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,""
```

and also matches this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,"",
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `.*?` can match commas.

Comment: The `.` in `(.*?,)` may also match commas. Try `([^,]*?,)` instead.

Comment: Your regex won't work for things like `a,b,"c,c",d,e,""`, so consider using a csv parser instead of a buggy regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex `^(.*?,){5}""` uses a non greedy part `(.*?,)` that tries to match as least as possible to get a match and repeat that 5 times.
The first 4 times you match `a,b,c,d,`. At the fifth time it tries to match `e,` followed by `""` but there is no match.

In the fifth repetition this part `(.*?,)` tries to match any character at least as possible (which can also be a comma itself because the dot matches also a comma) followed by a comma until it encounters a double quote so it matches `e,f,g,`.

Using a csv parser would be the better option, but if you want to use a regex for your example data you might match not a comma or a line break using a negated [character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) followed by pattern repeated 4 times that matches a comma followed by again matching not a comma and then match `""`

To match following comma separated data you could again match a comma followed by not a comma or a line break zero or more times and assert the end of the string `$`

[`^[^,\r\n]+(?:,[^,\r\n]+){4},""(?:,[^,\r\n]+)*$`](https://regex101.com/r/IJkSEq/1)